# Solving the equation $3\cos x+\frac{1}{2}=\cos ^{2}x\left(1+2\cos x\left(1+4\sin ^2x\right)\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve the equation:$$3\cos x+\frac{1}{2}=\cos ^{2}x\left(1+2\cos x\left(1+4\sin ^2x\right)\right)$$

To solve it, I tried writing the equation in term of $\cos x$. ( I denote $\cos x$ by $c$):

$$3c+\frac12=c^2(1+2c(5-4c^2))$$
$$3c+\frac12=c^2+10c^3-8c^5$$
$$16c^5-20c^3-2c^2+6c+1=0 \qquad\text{Where $c\in[-1,1]$}$$
I tried $c=\pm1,\pm\frac12,0$, but neither of them satisfied the equation. So I don't know how to find $\cos x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3\cos x+\frac{1}{2}=\cos ^{2}x\left(1+2\cos x\left(1+4\sin ^2x\right)\right)$

$ \displaystyle 6\cos x + 1 = (1 + \cos 2x) \left(1 + 2 \cos x (3 - 2 \cos2x)\right)$

$ \displaystyle 6\cos x + 1 = (1 + \cos 2x) (1 + 6 \cos x - 4 \cos x \cos 2x)$

$ \displaystyle 6\cos x + 1 = (1 + \cos 2x) (1 + 4 \cos x - 2 \cos 3x)$

$6\cos x + 1 = 5 \cos x + \cos 2x - \cos 5x + 1$

$\cos 2x = \cos x + \cos 5x$

$\cos 2x = 2 \cos 2x \cos 3x$

$\cos 2x = 0$ is a solution and if $\cos 2x \ne 0$,
$\cos 3x = \frac{1}{2}$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are right. We have $c=\pm\frac 12\sqrt 2$ as two of its roots. Hence, we get $x\in\{\pm\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain how you obtained $c=\pm\frac{\sqrt2}2$ ?

Comment: It's just a wild guess. If you have to solve it by hand, one of its roots should be $0$, $\frac 12$, $\frac 12 \sqrt 2$, $\frac 12 \sqrt 3$ or $1$. I am very sorry. Otherwise there is no good chance, i guess.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you :) I'll edit it.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that, because you know two roots of the polynomial you have, you can reduce the quintic you have (which is in general unsolvable) into a cubic (which is solvable). If you're interested in the other 3 solutions to $c$ (which are real, by the way) I can post an answer.

Comment: @Kyky I got your point. Thank you! No need for other answer.

Comment: All right then. In case you are interested here are the roots provided by WA: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16c%5E5-20c%5E3-2c%5E2%2B6c%2B1%3D0+roots